# retrieve IP address of client in logstash

Tags: logstash-grok

I am new to ELK stack and sending the application log file  to logstash server via tcp input method  using the below command

cat test.log | nc server port

Please let me know how can i retrieve the ip address of the client machine as field in logstash configuration file.

Comment: You should write a filter on the logstash and match it with grok pattern like: `%{IP:client}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the host IP when sending the message?

Comment: do i need to add the ip in the command cat test.log | nc server port? if so how to retrieve this in log stash configuration file as field